# C++ call from dll other dll with std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, dll, stdvector

I have a dll with the external method

```
extern "C" HAL_HASH_API basic_hash* getAlgorithmInstance( int algorithm );
```

and basic_hash has next method

```
// resets to the initial condition of the algorithm, 
// reset the counter and the current values
virtual void reset() = 0;

// performs all encryption cycle. 
virtual void hash( const byte*, uint64, vector_byte& ) = 0;
```

The first parameter `<data>` is a pointer to the beginning of the data, the second `<size>` parameter specifies the size of the hashed data, the third parameter `<hash>` is a buffer to store the hash value. vector size changes automatically.

and i have next types

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef unsigned long long uint64;
typedef std::vector< byte > vector_byte;
```

when i init variables and call `hash`

```
RUNSCRIPT_FUNCTION  runScript;
    basic_hash*  pointerBasicHash;
    // Load the DLL
    HINSTANCE dll = LoadLibrary(L"HAL.dll");
    if (dll == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to load library\n");
    }
    // Get the function pointer
    runScript = (RUNSCRIPT_FUNCTION)GetProcAddress(dll, "getAlgorithmInstance");
    if (runScript == NULL)
    {
        FreeLibrary(dll);
        printf("Unable to load function\n");
    }
    // Call the function 
    pointerBasicHash= (runScript)(0);
    vector_byte hashresult;
    hashresult.reserve(1024);
    uint64 size = 8;
    byte myString[] = "1234567";
    const byte* buff = &myString[0];

pointerBasicHash->reset();
pointerBasicHash->hash(buff, size, hashresult);
```

variable `hashresult` incorrectly, it contains a system variable PATH and trash.

EDIT basic_hash it's class

```
extern "C"  class  basic_hash
    {
    public:
        virtual ~basic_hash() {}
        virtual void reset() = 0;   
        virtual void hash(const byte*, uint64, vector_byte&) = 0;
    };
```

Comment: please post the signature of pointerBasicHash::hash()

Comment: sorry i edit code pointerBasicHash it is `basic_hash*  pointerBasicHash;`

Comment: Have you tested `hash` function of the class of `pointerBasicHash` you get?

Answer (score 1):

some possibilities:

1. The DLL has been compiled against a different version of the c++ runtime library
2. The DLL has been linked statically against the c+ runtime library
3. Your application has been linked statically against the c++ runtime library
4. The DLL has a bug in it.

Note. It is normally a very serious mistake to offer c++ standard library types in the interface of a DLL.

When the standard library changes (e.g. the compiler is upgraded) you may well need to recompile both the library and all applications that use it... which defeats the object of using a shared library in the first place.

Comment: what do you mean? " statically against "